# row в бутстрапе

Tags: bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такая задача, необходимо поставить по 2 иконки на мобильных устройствах.

Сейчас код работает так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="row sign text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Choose your language</h1>
      </div>
    </div>


     <div class="row lang1 text-center ">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="block2">
        <h2 >RUS</h2>
       <a href="#">  <img src="images/russia.png"> </a>

         </div>
         </div>


      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="block2"> 
        <h2>ENG</h2>
         <a href="#">   <img src="images/united-kingdom.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>


      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
         <div class="block2">
        <h2>GER</h2>
           <a href="#"> <img src="images/germany.png"></a>
      </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="block2">
        <h2>UKR</h2>
        <a href="#"> <img src="images/ukraine.png"></a>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>



   <div class="row lang2 ">

      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="block2">
        <h2>KZ</h2>
         <a href="#">   <img src="images/kazakhstan.png"></a>
      </div>
     </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
          <div class="block2">
        <h2>JP</h2>
         <img src="images/japan.png">
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
       <div class="block2"> 
       <h2>CN</h2>
          <a href="#">  <img src="images/china.png"></a>
      </div>
      </div>


      </div>


    </div>
```

1. Как убрать `.row` при маленьком разрешении?
2. Почему у меня не работают атрибуты `.col` для мобилок?

Answer (score 0):

`col-xs` отсутствует в новой версии, `col-12 col-sm-4`,по принципу сначала мобильные